# Webpack, css-minimizer-webpack-plugin vs mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I am always using `mini-css-extract-plugin` to optimize CSS. Today I found a new project, `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin), seems like this project do the same thing as `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

What is the advantage of `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin`? I read the docs and article from google, seems no one is talking about it? Should I use `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` to replace the `mini-css-extract-plugin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not for the same purpose. `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` is used to  compress the css files produced by `min-css-extract-plugin`. Here is how thy are used (I am in `webpack.config.js`):

```js
 //min-css-extract-plugin goes in the plugins array
 plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename:
        mode === "production"
          ? "css/[name].[contenthash].chunk.css"
          : "css/[name].css",
    }),
  ],
 //css-minimizer-webpack-plugin goes in the optimization object in minimizer array
 optimization:{
  minimizer: ["...", new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
 }
```